# Algebraically compute $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that: $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$ 
However all proofs I have seen resort to some kind of geometric appeal or otherwise fall to L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor series. However, I want an to see an proof that is purely algebraic (I mean least geometric intuition, mainly not diagrams to convince the reader of something, but obvious algebraic statements one after another) that uses nothing advanced like series and [I mean accessible to ordinary calculus beginner]... I do not want want elipson delta proofs but something that has quite evidently, no gaps.

Edit: Some comments have said sine cannot be defined without geometry or series. Well, I meant to say that we can assume that we know the unit circle definition. I only meant to say that we do not rely on diagrams in the proofs. We know the obvious facts that what sine  and radians are, etc. I did not mean it to take to formally and rigorously.

Hope you guys have some elegant and delightful proof of the kind. It is something which is bothering me for quite a while.

Comment: Please define $\sin x$.

Comment: How do you define the sine function?

Comment: What is the definition of $\sin$ you use in that case, because $\sin$ depends on a geometrical interpretation or on Taylor-series. Or it is defined in a way like $\sin(0)=0$ and $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sin(x)=-\sin(x)$.

Comment: Unit circle definition. I mean that the coordinates of a unit circle is (..). There is not much geometric tinkering in it. [And I mean we can accept geometric facts that are really obvious.]

Comment: The "unit circle" definition presumably says something like "at angle $\theta$, draw a ray; the point where it intersects the circle is $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. Would you be willing to modify that to "From the point $(1, 0)$, go counterclockwise around the circle for a *distance* of $\theta$; the point you find has coordinates $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$"? Or do you have a good definition for "angle," too? And are you willing to accept that for small $x$, $|\sin x| < |x|$? And what about the addition formulas for sine and cosine -- are they allowed?

Comment: @Sawarnik Then what issue do you have with the standard geometric proof. The only geometric fact that we use is that if $X\subset Y\subset Z$, then $A(X)\leq A(Y)\leq A(Z)$ where $A$ is the area function.

Comment: It looks like you want a proof without geometry, series. l'Hospital's Rule...without mathematics?! And you want something "algebraic" but "not advanced". I don't think there's such a thing, and the geometric proof is so simple that even high school students can understand it.

Comment: @IBWiglin I mean to say that the standard proof contains a lot of geometric appeal, for the layman. I am in no way saying that is wrong or formally rigged with holes. I mean to say for the layman reader [not formally], an proof that is algebraic in nature, that uses least geometry or diagrams to convince something but is straightforward algebraic statements.

Comment: @alexjo No that is not a duplicate because the question actually asks for geometric appeal where it is the opposite here.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have edited my question. And I was asking for a different kind of proof, not because people do not understand the standard proof.

Comment: If you take the unit circle definition of sine, there's no hope of finding a purely algebraic proof. In any case, what I show below is circular, but might convince you:
$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}\right)=\sin'(0)=\cos(0)=1.$$

Comment: @GitGud: I assume that when you say "there's no hope" you are referring to the transcendentality of $\sin.$  If I'm not mistaken, however, it is still possible to give an algebraic proof because $\arcsin$ is the integral of an algebraic function.  Maybe you would consider the integral definition to be different from the "unit circle definition of sine"?  (But the integral *is* the arc length of an arc of the unit circle.)

Comment: @WillOrrick Taking the geometric definition, at some point geometry is going to have to be used to turn this into a purely algebraic problem, that's what I mean. I consider the integral definition to be algebraic, no matter what intuition lies behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the difficulty many students have in understanding the proof of
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
is that it often comes too early in a calculus course, before one has learned integration, and therefore before one has learned how to think about arc lengths and areas.  Since arc length (or area) enters fundamentally into the definition of the $\sin$ function, the proofs that are usually given end up relying on geometric arguments that seem out of place next to the style of argumentation that one otherwise encounters in the first part of a calculus course.  I'm not suggesting that these arguments aren't rigorous, or that there aren't good reasons for bringing up trigonometric functions early—but I believe it can be satisfying to understand how this result comes about, rather straightforwardly, once one has defined the trigonometric functions in calculus terms.

If definite integration and arc length are unfamiliar to you, then this proof may not help.  However, the notion of arc length is used only to motivate a definition, and all one needs to know about the definite integral is that it represents the area under the curve.  This is used to obtain upper and lower bounds.

We make a purely algebraic definition of the $\arcsin$ function as follows.  For $y\in(-1,1)$ let
$$\arcsin y=\int_0^y\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$
Interpreted geometrically, this is, in fact, the formula for the signed length of the arc of the unit circle that extends from $(1,0)$ to $(\sqrt{1-y^2},y)$, and therefore indeed the $\arcsin$ function as usually defined, but this definition itself involves no geometry.  The $\sin$ function is then the inverse of this function, at least in an interval containing 0.  (In fact, in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2),$ where the symbol $\pi$ represents twice the upper bound of the $\arcsin$ function.  Thinking about how to extend the function to the entire real line is not needed for our purpose.)

We will first show that
$$
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\arcsin y}{y}=1.
$$
Since $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ is bounded above by $1,$ the integrand defining $\arcsin y$ is bounded below by $1,$ and, for $y$ positive, $\arcsin y$ is bounded below by $y.$  Hence $(\arcsin y)/y$ is bounded below by $1.$  Since, in the integral, $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ is bounded below by $\sqrt{1-y^2},$ the integrand is bounded above by $1/\sqrt{1-y^2},$ and, for $y$ positive, $\arcsin y$ is bounded above by $y/\sqrt{1-y^2}.$  Hence $(\arcsin y)/y$ is bounded above by $1/\sqrt{1-y^2}.$  Since $(\arcsin y)/y$ is an even function, the same bounds apply for $y$ negative.  But both of these bounds have limit $1$ as $y\to0,$ and the result follows from the squeeze theorem.

This is almost the result we want.  To finish, define the continuous function
$$
f(y)=\begin{cases}\frac{\arcsin y}{y} & \text{for $y\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\},$}\\
1 & \text{for $y=0,$}\end{cases}
$$
by plugging the hole at $y=0$ using the limit we just computed.  Let $g(x)=\sin x.$  Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $0$ and $g(0)=0,$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(g(x))=f\left(\lim_{x\to0} g(x)\right)=f(0)=1.
$$
But for $x\ne0,$ we have
$$
f(g(x))=\frac{\arcsin\sin x}{\sin x}=\frac{x}{\sin x},
$$
and so we have our result.

**Added remark:** Continuity of arcsin on (−1,1) follows in the definition I have used from continuity of the integrand and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (which actually implies differentiability). Continuity of sin follows from the easy fact that arcsin is one-to-one on (−1,1) and from the theorem that the inverse of a continuous, one-to-one function is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

We have $\sin x= AX$ and $\tan x=UT$ and $x=UX$ and geometrically we have
$$AX<UX<UT$$
hence dividing by $\sin x$ we obtain:
$$1<\frac{x}{\sin x}<\frac{1}{\cos x}$$
finaly pass to the limit $x\to0$ to find the desired result.

**Edit** To clear up the idea we have $$UX=x\times\text{the radius of the unit circle}=x$$

and the lenght of the arc $UX$ is greater than the hypothenus of the triangle $AUX$ which's greater than $AX$ so $AX<UX$ and finaly the area of the triangle $OUT$ is greater than the area of $OUX$ wich gives $UX<UT$.

Comment: $x \neq UX$ for any $x > 0$

Comment: To make $AX<UX<UT$ rigorous is a bit of a sub-challenge, after all $UX$ is a curve (hopefully a rectifyable one).

Comment: $x=UX$ requires you to measure in radians which requires another geometric fact, that arc length is the angle, which may or may not be acceptable! Since OP does not specify what can and can't be used, I am afraid that any answer may be acceptable or any answer may be unacceptable.

Comment: At least it should be specified whether $UX$ is to be taken the arc or, as all other terms used here, the shortest path (straight) from $U$ to $X$.

Comment: If we look for geometric proof we don't expect to take $x$ negative!

Comment: @AlexR Yes $UX=x\times \text{Radius of the unit circle}=x $

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Then, please add this ("$UX$ refers to the arc") to your answer, so I can remove the -1 again.

Comment: to make this rigourous one usually use the area of OAX, OUT (triangles) and the area of the circular sector OUX instead of the lengths. it gives the same inequalities. This proves $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$, and you can get $x\to 0^-$ by using the parity of $x \mapsto \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen We have $UX$ is greater than the hypothenus of the triangle $UAX$ which's greater than $AX$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Yes, the real noteworthy part (when dealing with lengths, not areas) is $UX<TU$.

Comment: But this is a (the) geometric proof the OP requested to be avoided...

Answer (score 1):

This may be more for fun than proof as all proofs require some notion of sine that is either a series or based on geometry.

You can start with the fact that $\sin(30^\circ) = 1/2$ and the half angle formula to calculate $\sin(15^\circ)$ and then $\sin(7.5^\circ)$ to get
$$
\sin(7.5^\circ) \approx .13053
$$
So $\sin(x)/x \approx 0.017403$.

In fact in the limit you will get
$$
\sin(x)/x \rightarrow 0.017453$$
So the limit is $1$ only if you measure in radians and you need some geometry to define a radian.

By the way, the limit of ratio of $\sin(x)/x$ in degrees is $\pi/180$, so you now have a simple way to calculate $\pi$!

Answer (score 0):

You might use the fundamental relation of trigonometry and the known limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1- \cos x}{x^2}= \frac{1}{2}$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}{x}= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2x}{x^2}}= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos x )}{x^2}(1+ \cos x)}= 1$$

Comment: How do we come upon the known limit?

Comment: using Taylor series that you certainly know. I don't see any other proof

Comment: ok :) I do not see anyway out too.

Comment: This is what I meant in my comment above: the "known limit" requires either geometry or slightly more advanced tools, and we're into a vicious circle...

Comment: Yeah, this is a nonproof.